# serialize and unserialize functions

Tags: php, serialization

I know serialization is the process of taking a complicated object and reducing it down to zeros and ones for either storage or transmission. But I'm confused about the interface Serializable
For example, we have colde like

```
class Artist implements Serializable {

 public function serialize() {
 return serialize(
 array("earliest" =>self::$earliestDate,
 "first" => $this->firstName,
 "last" => $this->lastName,
 "bdate" => $this->birthDate,
 "ddate" => $this->deathDate,
 "bcity" => $this->birthCity,
 "works" => $this->artworks
 );
 );
 }
 public function unserialize($data) {
 $data = unserialize($data);
 self::$earliestDate = $data['earliest'];
 $this->firstName = $data['first'];
 $this->lastName = $data['last'];
 $this->birthDate = $data['bdate'];
 $this->deathDate = $data['ddate'];
 $this->birthCity = $data['bcity'];
 $this->artworks = $data['works'];
 }
 //...
}
```

For example, unserialize($data)is the method that we implements, but how come it call itself inside the function like "$data = unserialize($data)",isn't it a infinite loop? Is the inside function unserialize($data) the same one as outside unserialize($data) function?

Comment: No, you're mixing up php functions `unserialize` and `serialize` in this case with your class methods, which are called differently.

Comment: No it is not the same function. This is not Java, `serialize`/`unserialize` refers to the library function, while `$this->serialize()` would refer to the `Artist::serialize()` function. To access an object's method "from within", you need to prefix it with `$this->`.

Comment: "ones and zeroes" - your object is already that in memory. serialization converts an in-memory object into a string for transmission/storage.